# Deploying Mediagoblin on Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: media

I am trying to deploy mediagoblin on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ according to the instructions found on ​https://mediagoblin.readthedocs.io/en/stable/siteadmin/deploying.html (the Python 3 variant). I've tried on both Raspbian Buster and Ubuntu MATE 18.04.2, but they both fail in the same place, as shown below.

```
mediagoblin@pi-mate:/srv/mediagoblin.example.org/mediagoblin$ ./bin/gmg dbupdate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin/gmg", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('mediagoblin', 'console_scripts', 'gmg')()
  File "/srv/mediagoblin.example.org/mediagoblin/mediagoblin/gmg_commands/__init__.py", line 148, in main_cli
    args.func(args)
  File "/srv/mediagoblin.example.org/mediagoblin/mediagoblin/gmg_commands/dbupdate.py", line 235, in dbupdate
    global_config, app_config = setup_global_and_app_config(args.conf_file)
  File "/srv/mediagoblin.example.org/mediagoblin/mediagoblin/init/__init__.py", line 48, in setup_global_and_app_config
    global_config, validation_result = read_mediagoblin_config(config_path)
  File "/srv/mediagoblin.example.org/mediagoblin/mediagoblin/init/config.py", line 89, in read_mediagoblin_config
    mainconfig_defaults = copy.copy(config_spec.get("DEFAULT", {}))
  File "/srv/mediagoblin.example.org/mediagoblin/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 96, in copy
    rv = reductor(4)
  File "/srv/mediagoblin.example.org/mediagoblin/lib/python3.6/site-packages/configobj-5.0.6-py3.6.egg/configobj.py", line 482, in __reduce__
  File "/srv/mediagoblin.example.org/mediagoblin/lib/python3.6/site-packages/configobj-5.0.6-py3.6.egg/configobj.py", line 557, in __getitem__
  File "/srv/mediagoblin.example.org/mediagoblin/lib/python3.6/site-packages/configobj-5.0.6-py3.6.egg/configobj.py", line 549, in _interpolate
  File "/srv/mediagoblin.example.org/mediagoblin/lib/python3.6/site-packages/configobj-5.0.6-py3.6.egg/configobj.py", line 352, in interpolate
  File "/srv/mediagoblin.example.org/mediagoblin/lib/python3.6/site-packages/configobj-5.0.6-py3.6.egg/configobj.py", line 330, in recursive_interpolate
  File "/srv/mediagoblin.example.org/mediagoblin/lib/python3.6/site-packages/configobj-5.0.6-py3.6.egg/configobj.py", line 417, in _parse_match
  File "/srv/mediagoblin.example.org/mediagoblin/lib/python3.6/site-packages/configobj-5.0.6-py3.6.egg/configobj.py", line 386, in _fetch
configobj.MissingInterpolationOption: missing option "here" in interpolation.
```

All of the steps leading up to that have executed successfully.  Any ideas what could be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

This issue was a bug we've fixed in MediaGoblin 0.10.0. See the [release notes](https://mediagoblin.readthedocs.io/en/stable/siteadmin/relnotes.html) for details. Please try your installation again following the deployment guide you mentioned and [get in touch](https://mediagoblin.readthedocs.io/en/stable/siteadmin/help.html) if you hit further issues.

*(I'm a co-maintainer of MediaGoblin)*